# Unable to use the 'this' pointer in a const member function

Tags: c++, constants

I was going through: [C++ FAQs about inheritance](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-base) and decided to implement it just to learn it:

```
#include "Shape.h"
 
 void Shape::print() const
 {
     float a = this->area();  // area() is pure virtual
     ...
 }
```

Now, everything (well, almost) works as described in the FAQ except that `print()` is `const` and so it can't access the `this` pointer. As soon as you take out `const`, it works.

The C++ FAQ has been around for a while and is usually pretty good. Is this a mistake?
Does it have a typo or am I wrong? If I'm wrong, I would like to know how is it possible to access the `this` pointer in a `const` function.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Given a choice between me perhaps not understanding correctly, or an almost 20-year old oft-cited reference having a mistake or typo on a trivial case, I tend to suspect I might be missing something.

Comment: BTW, save yourself some typing time and refrain from `this->`.  It is not needed in C++. *Perhaps a leftover trait from Java?*

Comment: lefover trait from Java??? you must be kidding.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that the area() function is not const.  If that function was const, then this would compile fine.  Since your inside a const function, the this pointer is const and therefore you can only call const functions on it.

Answer (score 8):

Why couldn't `this` be accessed? The point is, only `const` members and methods can be used. So if `Shape::area()` is declared `const`, there is no problem. Also, you can freely read data member values, but not assign to them:

```
class Shape 
{
  int i;
  void print() const;
  virtual float area() const = 0;
  virtual void modify() = 0;
};

void Shape::print() const
{
  float a = this->area(); // call to const member - fine
  int j = this->i;        // reading const member - fine

  this->modify();         // call to non const member - error
  this->i++;              // assigning to member - error
}
```

Comment: You're right..thanks. I actually got it right after typed the question, but will accept the answer and leave for others to learn.

Answer (score 1):

If `print` is defined as `const`, then it can use `this` to access `const` members but not to access non-const members: so it *can* invoke `this->area()` if-and-only-if the `area` method is declared as `const` (i.e. if the `area` method promises that if it's invoked then it won't mutate its `Shape` instance).

Answer (score 1):

It is also a good practice to declare all functions as const by default, and only not do so when you actually need to modify the object. This will also help finding errors of the kind where some function modifies something it is not meant to.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can access the `this` pointer, but in  a `const` function it becomes a pointer to  a `const` object. Remember, the `this` pointer isn't  a real pointer instance, so it can change its type at different points in the program.